# Datatable values comparison

Tags: c#, sql, database

I want to get value from my datatable which has two columns. Name and OrderTime. I want to subtract corresponding value from time in a text box. I am referring to datatable values using following code. I can get result in

```
string First = (mydatabaseDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[1][2].ToString());
MessageBox.Show(First);
```

But why I can't compare and get value with following code.
thanks

```
private void comboBox_suburb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox_suburb.SelectedValue!=null)
        if (comboBox_suburb.SelectedItem.ToString() == mydatabaseDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString())
        {
            int timetosub = Convert.ToInt32(mydatabaseDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][j + 1]);
            totaltime = bdtime + timetosub;

            tmpk = totaltime;
            time3 = time2.AddMinutes(-tmpk);
            textBox_ordertostart.Text = time3.ToString("hh:mm tt");        
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you set the DataSource for the comboBox ? What is the type of the items ? What is the datatype of the DataTable Columns ? The provided information is not enough

Comment: Please show values that you are checking here: `comboBox_suburb.SelectedItem.ToString() == mydatabaseDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString()`

Comment: So its a datatable comprise of three columns. First col is jusjust I'd which visual studio set auto as 1, 2 and so on. Nenext col is name which are string or ncharvar50. Third is iOrderTime as int.   I clicked on arrow on top right corner of    combobox where I bind the Name column of my datatable. Now I want each corresponding value in front of each name in Name col and subtract it from a time in textbox. Thanks

Comment: The code u asking output for is giving nothing. That's what I I  am asking. How I change the value to be subtracted from a time in textbox with change in value of combobox without putting each name in if condition rather do it with database. Thanks

Comment: I have ann idea of equalizing int i and j with combobox index number but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i solved the problem.
Thanks for your feedback guys!

```
private void comboBox_suburb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:\Users\WoolsValley\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication17\WindowsFormsApplication17\mydatabase.mdf; Integrated Security = True");
        con.Open();
        int i = comboBox_suburb.SelectedIndex;
        int j = 1;

        comboBox_suburb.ValueMember = mydatabaseDataSet.Tables[0].Columns[1].ToString();


        if (comboBox_suburb.SelectedItem.ToString() == (mydatabaseDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString())) ;

            {
                int timetosub = Convert.ToInt32(mydatabaseDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][j + 1]);

                totaltime = bdtime + timetosub;


                tmpk = totaltime;
                time3 = time2.AddMinutes(-tmpk);
                textBox_ordertostart.Text = time3.ToString("hh:mm tt");

            }
    }
```